# How to be sure malloc will alloc in a different area

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I've a weird problem with malloc. I have this typedefs:

```
typedef struct buffer {
    int D;
    int T;
    unsigned int current_size;
    unsigned int max_size;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t non_pieno;
    pthread_cond_t non_vuoto;
    msg_t** messages;

    struct buffer* (*buffer_init)(unsigned int);
    void (*buffer_destroy)(struct buffer*);
} buffer_t;
```

And this is the buffer_init and buffer_destroy function:

```
buffer_t* buffer_init(unsigned int maxsize)
{
    buffer_t* new_buffer = (buffer_t*)malloc(sizeof(buffer_t));
    msg_t** new_messages = (msg_t**)calloc(maxsize, sizeof(msg_t**));

    pthread_mutex_t mx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t np = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t nv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

    new_buffer->T = 0;
    new_buffer->D = 0;
    new_buffer->current_size = 0;
    new_buffer->max_size = maxsize;
    new_buffer->messages = new_messages;
    new_buffer->mutex = mx;
    new_buffer->non_pieno = np;
    new_buffer->non_vuoto = nv;

    new_buffer->buffer_init = buffer_init;
    new_buffer->buffer_destroy = buffer_destroy;

    return new_buffer;
}

void buffer_destroy(buffer_t* buffer) {
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&buffer->mutex);
    free(buffer);
}
```

If I print (after each call to the proper buffer_destroy buffer_init sequence) the pointers that I obtain they are most the same!!
E.g

```
buffer_t* my_buff;

my_buff = buffer_init(1);
printf("%d", my_buff); //e.g 10023
printf("%d", my_buff->mutex); //e.g 56778

buffer_destroy(my_buff);
my_buff = buffer_init(1);
printf("%d", my_buff); //10023 again!!!
printf("%d", my_buff->mutex); //56778 again!!!
```

I'm pretty sure the problems is that something goes wrong with the initialization and deallocation of the buffer_t, do you know, in order:

a) How to properly deallocate buffer into buffer_destroy?
b) How to properly init the mutex? I want to create a new mutex with each call!
c) I have to malloc for D and T? I have to dealloc them??

Thanks for your time!
A.

Comment: Why do you think that this is the problem? If memory is released, it can be reused. Try to allocate two buffers without releasing them, in this case addresses must be different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't look like a problem! You've allocated some memory, then released it back to the system. Then you've asked for some more memory of the same size, and the malloc system has noticed that there's some memory available of that size - the same memory that it gave you before!

If you remove the call to `buffer_destroy()` you should see that you get different values. (By the way I recommend using "%p" for printing pointer values, rather than "%d").

Comment: It may seems is not a problem, but I suspect that due to the static PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER the mutex it's not deallocated with buffer_destroy. As side effect, I have two different buffers that share the same mutex, with a beautiful deadlock on linux machine and a segmentation fault on my Mac Os :(

Comment: @Alfredo: It looks like you have a lot of underlying misunderstandings. It's not "the same mutex" but a new mutex at the same address. If anything was still referring to and trying to use the old mutex after you called `free`, your code is broken. Perhaps you should explain more of what's going on.

Comment: I know (and I hope) that it should be a new mutex at the same address, but I'm afraid that the static mutex initialization with PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER preserves the mutex to be freed after my call to free(buffer) :S

Comment: @Alfredo Di Napoli: I'm afraid I have to agree with @R. - on Linux I'm certain, because I know the code well, that re-initialising a mutex at the same address with PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER will *completely* reinitialise the mutex, leaving no trace of anything previously at the same address, *providing that* no other thread is waiting on the mutex at the time. And as R. says, if another thread is using the mutex at the time you free it, then *that* is the problem you need to fix, not the fact that a new mutex gets reallocated in the same place :-)

Comment: Thanks guys!! I hope to fix it soon!!

Comment: Although it's unlikely to be a problem on linux, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER is to be used for static initializers *only*. (that is, mutexes with the lifetime of a static object). You should not use it for a local variable, and then copy that mutex , copying a mutex with the = operator is undefined by posix. Use pthread_mutex_init()

Answer (score 0):

I think that malloc has an internal table, and when you release memory (with free), the "cell" is just set to "busy = 0" then the memory is available for other data.
So there's not issue here imo.